# When i try to add a new mesh it dosent show up

Tags: modeling, object-mode

when I try to add a mesh it does not show up in the viewpoint it only shows up in the scene collection. The only thing that shows up in the veiwport is a cube. The viewpoint and the render view are both checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> and select all the objects you want, then hit Enter.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It did not work do you have any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

you might be in local view - hit `/` key to toggle between local and regular view.